# How can I simplify a formula for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-data-validation

How can I make this formula simpler:

`=SUM('DAY1'!P39,'DAY2'!P39,'DAY3'!P39,'DAY4'!P39,'DAY5'!P39,'DAY6'!P39,'DAY7'!P39,'DAY8'!P39,'DAY9'!P39,'DAY10'!P39,'DAY11'!P39,'DAY12'!P39,'DAY13'!P39,'DAY14'!P39,'DAY15'!P39,'DAY16'!P39,'DAY17'!P39,'DAY18'!P39,'DAY19'!P39,'DAY20'!P39,'DAY21'!P39,'DAY22'!P39,'DAY23'!P39,'DAY24'!P39,'DAY25'!P39,'DAY26'!P39,'DAY27'!P39,'DAY28'!P39,'DAY29'!P39,'DAY30'!P39,'DAY31'!P39)`

I am trying to get data from multiple sheets onto one page to track deals throughout the month and I'm having to copy, paste and edit the formula. In excel, this formula would be `=SUM('DAY1:DAY31'!P39)`

Is there a way to make this easier?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to not store all your data in one sheet?

Answer (score 1):

**Step1** Create a new sheet called `AllDays` in cell `B1` put

`=Arrayformula(if(A:A,,"'Day"&row(A:A)&"'!P39"))`

**Step2** In cell `C1` put

```
=iferror(indirect(B:B),"")
```

**Step3** Manually drag cell `C1` to the bottom of the spreadsheet

Now you can simply `sum` this `AllDays` column C to get the total. Should be pretty simple to use the other columns to grab other specific cells.